# Apache2 SSL HTTPS not working despite my following the guides

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I'm trying to configure https support for Apache2 running in an Ubuntu instance in AWS.  I've enabled SSL support in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:

```
# grep -v '^[   ]*#' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf | grep -v '^$'
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName miit.co
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/miit_co.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/miit-co.key
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and the configuration as a whole is valid:

```
# apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

The file `/etc/ssl/private/miit-co.key` is a "PEM RSA private key" which I generated (can't remember how exactly now) and `/etc/ssl/certs/miit_co.crt` is one of **two** files I received back from my non-technical boss, the other being `miit_co.pem` which I don't know what do with.  I also have a `csr.pem` (PEM certificate request) which I generated and sent to my boss.  I did not send him the private key file.  Maybe I have to do something with that `miit_co.pem` file.

When I start Apache (`systemctl start apache2`) there is nothing in `/var/log/apache2/{error,access}.log` to indicate that Apache2 is *not* running normally.  However, *https://www.digicert.com/help/* when given our site name (miit.co) just spins and spins.  I wonder if there is something other than Apache stopping *https* access, since http://miit.co works as expected (it redirects in fact but that's not relevant here) but https://miit.co just times out.  `ufw status` replies `disabled`.

`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` includes `ssl.{conf,load}`.

If I try curl on the local machine, it indicates that Apache is being reached by *https* requests:

```
# curl https://localhost
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (miit.co) does not match target host name 'localhost'
# curl https://miit.co/michael
(hangs)
```

Any suggestions as to why *https:* access just hangs?

Comment: Just for completeness, for anyone reading this later, that `miit_co.pem` file has to be the subject of a `SSLCACertificateFile` declaration in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your post with aws-services, I assume your running ubuntu on an AWS EC2 instance.  If so, the problem is likely with the security group associated with the instance.  I recommend reviewing the EC2 instance's security group and adding a rule to allow inbound HTTPS from everywhere.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.